# Сделать выбор между less и sass

Tags: css, framework, sass, less

Пришло время изучить какой-нибудь CSS фреймворк, естественно выбор стал между LESS и SASS, оба нацелены на гибкость подхода к оформлению стилей. Подскажите какой выбрать, чтоб его возможности перекрывали слабейшего из них для того, что бы не тратить время на изучение уже имеющихся полученных возможностей из другого фреймворка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Синтаксис у фич в препроцессорах очень схож между собой, поэтому, изучив их в LESS, и перейдя потом на SASS, у вас не возникнет проблем со старыми знаниями. В этом плане изучать можно любые фреймворки в любом порядке.

По возможностям LESS и SASS близки. Twitter Bootstrap с четвертой версии официально перешел с LESS на SASS. Учитывая популярность бутстрапа, это решение однозначно сыграет на скорости развития SASS по сравнению с LESS.

Но советую обратить внимание на Stylus. С тех пор, как за его развитие взялись ребята из команды яндекс.почты - препроцессор растет очень быстрыми темпами, и по фичам он уже далеко впереди SASS. Те возможности, которые уже есть в Stylus, в SASS висят лишь в виде открытых issue, запланированных на неопределенное будущее. В лучшем случае в SASS мы их увидим через год. А в Stylus можно использовать уже сейчас.

К тому же у Stylus более гибкий синтаксис. Можете писать в CSS/SCSS стиле со скобками, можете в SASS стиле с отступами. Можете опускать двоеточия в css-свойствах, можете присваивать переменные и через двоеточие как в SASS, и через равно, как в императивных языках.

По скорости - SASS и LESS на одном уровне, Stylus в 1.5 раза быстрее. Но у SASS есть версия препроцессора, написанная на C - LibSass, она очень быстрая - в 3.5 раза быстрее Stylus. Быстрее нее - только PostCSS, но это уже не препроцессор в классическом понимании. Можете посмотреть и в его сторону, кстати - развивается в неплохом темпе.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. а не знаете по распространенности какой препроцессор преобладает в наибольшем количестве? по тому что я думаю что столкнусь с поддержкой чужого кода, выигрыш можно получить и за счет этого.

Comment: Смотря куда пойдете. В разных сообществах приживаются те или иные препроцессоры. В Ruby on Rails, например - это sass и coffeescript (вместо js), они идут из коробки и используются подавляющим большинством разработчиков. Если же пойдете во фронтенд (react, webpack, browserify), там преобладают node.js решения, в частности PostCSS и плагины к нему. А по js-части - ES6 и babel.

Comment: а в классической веб-разработке (php + js + css + html) какой наиболее востребован?

Comment: Это может зависеть от CMS или CMF на php. Тоже могут быть разные предпочтения. Рекомендую вам попробовать всего понемногу. Начать с самого легкого и со временем попробовать остальное.