# ссылка одного CSS внутри другого CSS

Tags: css

Вопрос чисто теоретический и простой, но в интернетах не нашел.
Как реализовать вот это:

```
.leftBlock{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  //myPadding
}
myPadding{
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

То есть, когда элементов мало можно это без проблем вручную прописать, но если много, то напряжно. Как правильно ссылаться на другие .css ?

Comment: Вам [сюда](https://toster.ru/q/175853) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557430/%D0%A1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-less-%D0%B8-sass) можно почитать. А с помощью стандартных функций `css`, этого к сожалению, не сделать.

Comment: Есть пре-/постпроцессоры (less, sass, stylus, postcss и тд). Можно просто в html писать у элемента несколько классов (в частности «атомарный css»). А вообще обычно это не очень-то и нужно. Сегодня у ваших блоков одинаковый padding, а завтра дизайнер решит, что у парочки блоков отступ должен быть другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать переменные в этом случае. Например вот так:

```
<style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        --standart-padding: 1.5em;
      }
      .container {
        width: 100%;
        background: #222;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .template {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 40px auto;
        background: #999;
        padding: var(--standart-padding);
      }
      .another {
        width: 40%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        padding: var(--standart-padding);
        background: #777;
      }
    </style>

    <section class="container">
      <article class="template">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo quas
          quod sed velit, dignissimos autem ducimus, voluptates dolor eius,
          omnis nisi! Laudantium.
        </p>
      </article>
      <article class="template">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo quas
          quod sed velit, dignissimos autem ducimus, voluptates dolor eius,
          omnis nisi! Laudantium.
        </p>
      </article>
      <article class="template">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo quas
          quod sed velit, dignissimos autem ducimus, voluptates dolor eius,
          omnis nisi! Laudantium.
        </p>
      </article>
      <article class="another">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo quas
          quod sed velit, dignissimos autem ducimus, voluptates dolor eius,
          omnis nisi! Laudantium.
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
```